# SAR ADC offset calculation

Tags: adc

In the photo shown bellow we have a calculation for SAR ADC voltage NODE sighned as Vout.
Without offset we have -Vin voltage from the sampling stage and the Vfs with capactior voltage divider (depending on the switches)

How all thes stage will be affected when we have Vos on the opamp?

[image]

Comment: The input referred offset of a comparator (or even op-amp but an op-amp should not be used as a comparator) is due to the mismatch between pairs of transistors. Instead of a comparator tripping at exactly 500mV (on - input with + grounded) between a 0 and 1 on its output, it may require 504mV to switch levels. Thus a 4mV offset. You can model this as a 4mV voltage source in series with your inverting input.

Comment: I am asking how i build the equation with the offset

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? It isn't clear at all what you want to do.